# SQL Server: Intermittent Invalid object name 'dbo.computed_view1'. Could not use view or function 'dbo.view2' because of binding errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a view; let's call it view1. This view is complex and slow. It cannot be made into an indexed view because it uses left joins and various other trickery. As such, we created a stored procedure which basically:

1. obtains an exclusive lock
2. selects * into computed_view1_tmp from view1;  (slow)
3. creates indexes on the above computed table (slow)
4. renames computed_view1 to computed_view1_todelete; and does the same for its indexes (assumed fast)
5. renames computed_view1_tmp to computed_view1; and does the same for its indexes (assumed fast)
6. drops the table computed_view1_todelete (slow)
7. releases the lock.

We run this procedure when we know we're changing the data in our web application. We then have other views, such as view2 using computed_view1 instead of view1.

Once in a while, we get:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.computed_view1'. Could not use view or
>   function 'dbo.view2 because of binding errors.

I assume this is because we're trying to access dbo.computed_view1 at the same time as it's being renamed. I assume this is a very short period, but the frequency I am seeing this error in my logs makes me wonder if something else might be at play. I'm getting the error many times per day on a site with about a dozen users active throughout the day.

In development, this procedure takes about five seconds given the amount of data in the view. Renaming is instantaneous. In production, it must be taking longer but I don't understand why.  I once saw the procedure fail to obtain the exclusive lock within 90 seconds.

Any thoughts on how to fix or a better solution?

Edit: Extra notes on my locking - maybe I'm not doing this right:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @result int
EXEC @result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'lock_computed_view1', @LockMode = 'Exclusive',  @LockTimeout = 90
IF @result NOT IN ( 0, 1 )   -- Only successful return codes
    BEGIN
      PRINT @result
      RAISERROR ( 'Lock failed to acquire...', 16, 1 )
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
           // rest of the magic 
        END

EXEC @result = sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'lock_computed_view1'  
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're locking and transaction scope is right I would expect other transactions to wait and never see the view missing. This might be a SQL Server idiosyncrasy that I don't know about.

It is often possible to do without dynamic DDL. Here are two ways to do it:

1. `TRUNCATE` the computed table and insert into it. This takes an exclusive automatically. No need to rename. All of this is atomic and supports rollback.
2. Use a staging table with the same schema. Work on that. So far no service interruption at all. Then, `SWITCH PARTITION` the staging table with the production table. This is quick and atomic. This does not require Enterprise Edition.

With these approaches the problem is solved by just not renaming.

Comment: TRUNCATE was my first approach in development, but it left the system without rows for too long (ex: 5 seconds) at precisely the time where I needed to see them (right after saving a change). Had not thought of SWITCH PARTITION.

Comment: When you use a transaction no one will see that the table has no rows. Everyone will wait for 5sec. Might be acceptable.